# Biblatex either uses 1 author or all 12 of them.

Tags: biblatex, citing

Due to space constraints, I need to use exactly 2 or 3 authors on my bibliography. However, setting any of `minnames, maxnames, mincitenames, maxcitenames, maxbibnames` doesn't work. It's either 1 author or all 12. Is there any way to fix this?

**MWE 1:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   % Prepare document

% Set up bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys,articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=3,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    Whatever \cite{Katmis2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**MWE 2:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   % Prepare document

% Set up bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys,articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,maxcitenames=3,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    Whatever \cite{Katmis2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**test.bib**

```
@article{Katmis2016,
author = {Katmis, Ferhat and Lauter, Valeria and Nogueira, Flavio S. and Assaf, Badih A. and Jamer, Michelle E. and Wei, Peng and Satpati, Biswarup and Freeland, John W. and Eremin, Ilya and Heiman, Don and Jarillo-Herrero, Pablo and Moodera, Jagadeesh S.},
doi = {10.1038/nature17635},
journal = {Nature},
month = {may},
number = {7604},
pages = {513--516},
title = {{A high-temperature ferromagnetic topological insulating phase by proximity coupling}},
volume = {533},
year = {2016}
}
```

Comment: Try `maxbibnames=3,minbibnames=2` (`maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` are only for citations in text). Note: a paper with only one author can't _"use exactly 2 or 3 authors"..._

Comment: Or of course only `maxnames=3, minnames=2` to influence both citations and the bibliography at the same time. Alternatively you can also set `maxnames=3, minnames=3`.

Comment: All of the papers in my .bib have 3 authors as a minimum. I've tried quite a few combinations of the  options (and on their own as suggested), but it's still citing either 1 or 12. Thanks though

Comment: @Paul Gaborit  your suggestion worked on my laptop, it still won't work on my desktop for some reason but I'll try to figure that out later, thanks! Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **bibliographies**, if the number of authors is less than or equal to `maxbibnames`, the names of all authors appear. Otherwise, `minbibnames` authors appear followed by "*et al.*"
<sub>(constraint: `minbibnames` ≤ `maxbibnames`).</sub>

In **citations**, if the number of authors is less than or equal to `maxcitenames`, the names of all authors appear. Otherwise, `mincitenames` authors appear followed by "*et al.*".
<sub>(constraint: `mincitenames` ≤ `maxcitenames`).</sub>

To define the same thresholds in citations and bibliographies, use `maxnames` and `minnames`.

So, to use *"exactly 1, 2 or 3 authors in your bibliography"*, you may use `maxbibnames=3,minbibnames=3`.

(reference: p.46, *biblatex* manual, v3.5)